# Post data with XMLHttpRequest in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have two forms, one is a copy of the other. I want to send some data to the server and if it is successful the server must return a number to me otherwise it must return null. Of course, in the second form, several fields are deleted and set to constant values. Both forms send data to one api. In the first form, the sending operation is done correctly and returns a number, while in the second form, the same code returns an empty string and the data is not registered on the server.

First form:
main.js :

```
 class FormData {
    constructor(
        ID,
        IDPresenter,
        IDGenre,
        IDTradingMethod,
        IDRegional,
        IDJob,
        IDProduct,
        FirstName,
        LastName,
        NationalCode,
        Address,
        PostalCode,
        Comment,
        ClientCount,
        TelNo,
        MobileNo,
        Email,
        BusinessName,
        RequestDate,
        IDConfirmState,
        BirthDate,
        IDPersonType
    ) {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.IDPresenter = IDPresenter;
        this.iDGenre = IDGenre;
        this.iDTradingMethod = IDTradingMethod;
        this.iDRegional = IDRegional;
        this.iDJob = IDJob;
        this.IDProduct = IDProduct;
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.NationalCode = NationalCode;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.PostalCode = PostalCode;
        this.Comment = Comment;
        this.ClientCount = ClientCount;
        this.TelNo = TelNo;
        this.MobileNo = MobileNo;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.BusinessName = BusinessName;
        this.RequestDate = RequestDate;
        this.IDConfirmState = IDConfirmState;
        this.BirthDate = BirthDate;
        this.IDPersonType = IDPersonType;
    }
}

function insert() {
    

    let iD = 0;
    let iDPresenter = DomIdentifierCode.value;
    let iDGenre = DomGender.value;
    let iDTradingMethod = DomTrade.value;
    let iDRegional = DomRegion.value;
    let iDJob = DomJobs.value;
    let iDProduct = DomSoftwareType.value;
    let firstName = DomFirstName.value;
    let lastName = DomLastName.value;
    let nationalCode = DomInternationalCode.value;
    let address = DomAddress.value;
    let postalCode = DomPostalCode.value;
    let comment = DomComment.value;
    let clientCount = DomClientCount.value;
    let telNo = DomTelephone.value;
    let mobileNo = DomPhoneNumber.value;
    let email = DomEmail.value;
    let businessName = DomShopName.value;
    let requestDate = DomObjCal2.value;
    let iDConfirmState = 0;
    let birthDate = DomObjCal1.value; //DomBirthday.value;
    let iDPersonType = 1;

    let formData = new FormData(
        iD,
        iDPresenter,
        iDGenre,
        iDTradingMethod,
        iDRegional,
        iDJob,
        iDProduct,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        nationalCode,
        address,
        postalCode,
        comment,
        clientCount,
        telNo,
        mobileNo,
        email,
        businessName,
        requestDate,
        iDConfirmState,
        birthDate,
        iDPersonType
    );
    console.log(formData);
    
    
        const XHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
        // Define what happens in case of error
        XHR.addEventListener(' error', function(event) {
            alert('There is a problem');
        });
        // Set up our request
        XHR.open('POST', myUrl);
        XHR.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        XHR.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

        // Send our FormData object; HTTP headers are set automatically

        XHR.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (XHR.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (XHR.status == 200) {
                    var data = XHR.responseText;
                    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(jsonResponse);
                }
            }
        };
        XHR.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
        clearForm();
        
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    
}
```

Second form :
main.js :

```
function insert() {
    

    let iD = 0;
    let iDPresenter = DomIdentifierCode.value;
    let iDGenre = DomGender.value;
    let iDTradingMethod = DomTrade.value;
    let iDRegional = DomRegion.value;
    let iDJob = DomJobs.value;
    let iDProduct = 0;
    let firstName = DomFirstName.value;
    let lastName = DomLastName.value;
    let nationalCode = DomInternationalCode.value;
    let address = DomAddress.value;
    let postalCode = DomPostalCode.value;
    let comment = DomComment.value;
    let clientCount = 0;
    let telNo = DomTelephone.value;
    let mobileNo = DomPhoneNumber.value;
    let email = DomEmail.value;
    let businessName = DomShopName.value;
    let requestDate = 2020 - 10 - 23;
    let iDConfirmState = 0;
    let birthDate = DomObjCal1.value; //DomBirthday.value;
    let iDPersonType = 2;

    let formData = new FormData(
        iD,
        iDPresenter,
        iDGenre,
        iDTradingMethod,
        iDRegional,
        iDJob,
        iDProduct,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        nationalCode,
        address,
        postalCode,
        comment,
        clientCount,
        telNo,
        mobileNo,
        email,
        businessName,
        requestDate,
        iDConfirmState,
        birthDate,
        iDPersonType
    );
    console.log(formData);
    
    
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        

        // Define what happens in case of error
        debugger;
        xhr.addEventListener(' error', function(event) {
            alert('Ther is a problem');
        });
        // Set up our request
        xhr.open('POST', myUrl);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');

        // Send our FormData object; HTTP headers are set automatically

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    var data = xhr.responseText;
                    var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(JSON.stringify(formData));
        clearForm();
    
        $('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
    
}


First form :
```

[image]

```
Second form :
```

[image]

Any one can help me?

Comment: null from a back-end API can often register as `""` in Javascript.

Comment: Do you know why data is not registered on server?

Comment: let requestDate = 2020 - 10 - 23; is a bit suspect.

Comment: Thanke you....You are right...I solved it .  let requestDate = '2020' + '-' + '10' + '-' + '23';